# How can I programmatically detect what directory an executable is in when it is run?

Tags: macos, cocoa, filepath, nsfilemanager

I've been playing around with Command Line Tools in Xcode and I have stumbled upon something that I have no clue how to handle.

If I build my tool, and put the executable on the desktop, is it possible to run the executable and have the output be the directory that 'self' is in? Meaning, can I log 'Hey I am in: /Users/me/Desktop'?

And then if I were to move that file elsewhere, have that change?

Is there some sort of environment variable I could use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, wow. Didn't think I'd be able to find an answer this quick but here [it](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/command-line-tools-tutorial-1/) is. Turns out that the location of the file is one of the arguments passed into main.

Here is the code:

```
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"argv[%d] = '%s'", i, argv[i]);
    }
```

Interesting!

Comment: Yep, `argv[0]` for any C/C++/Objective-C program is the program being run.

Comment: Why create the `NSString`? Just do `NSLog(@"argv[%d] = '%s'", i, argv[i]);`

Comment: I just grabbed the code from the referenced link. Updated with yours. Thanks!